# Use Autodesk authentication v2 with ASP.NET Core

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am testing v2 of Forge Authentication using ASP.NET core. However, it doesn't seem to work. I created a minimal repo that can be found [here](https://github.com/EMostafaAli/ForgeAuthV2Test).

To reproduce:

- Create an app at https://aps.autodesk.com (web server app)
- Clone the repo above and put in client Id & secret
- Run the app and go to privacy page

After signing in I got an error message says `OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'The request is missing a required parameter 'code_verifier'.', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.`

Comment: What kind of authentication exactly are you trying to implement? 2-legged or 3-legged? The error message says `code_verifier` which is strange because that parameter is only required for PKCE authentication which you specifically disabled in your sample app.

Comment: Also, were you following any specific tutorial when building your sample app?

Comment: It is a 3-legged auth. I was surprised as well with this error message. However, I replace Autodesk authority with other authority the code works well. If you have a working example for .NET, please share it with me.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial in .NET [APS Tutorials](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/) which is using the package `Autodesk.Forge`.

Comment: FYI the APS tutorials are using Authentication **v1**. Version 2 is very recent and we haven't updated the SDKs yet.

Comment: With that said, @Mostafaabdo, if you don't need v2 specifically, I would also suggest to follow https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/ to implement a 3-legged OAuth workflow.

Comment: I am aware of the suggested tutorial. However, I was hoping that you can check the repo I provided. I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package to authorize the app & get token. It was working with v1 but not v2 see this issue: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/760